# Debugger not reaching select statement in jQuery.autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Dynamic Grid in the `ASP.NET` page. When I click `Add User`, it creates an empty record with Textbox controls and when the user types something in the first `Textbox - UserName`, it should pull the `UserNames` from the Database and `autocomplete` should work for that Textbox control.

I have implemented `jQuery.autocomplete` function as below.

```
jQuery("#" + e.id).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var txtSearch = jQuery("#" + e.id).attr("id");                        
        var t = jQuery("#" + txtSearch).val();      
        var URL = "../Users.aspx?UserName=" + t;           
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                switch (data) {                        
                    case 'NOVALUESFOUND':
                        var rftspanID = e.id.replace("txt", "span");
                        break;
                    default:
                        var rftspanID = e.id.replace("txt", "span");
                        var rows = data.split("|");
                        var jsStr = "var datalist=[";
                        for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
                            var s = rows[i].toString();
                            s = s.replace("'", "\\'");
                            s = s.replace('"', "\\'");
                            var row = s.split("~");

                            jsStr += "{id:'" + row[0].toString() + "'";
                            jsStr += ",name:'" + row[1].toString() + "'},";
                        }
                        jsStr = jsStr.slice(0, jsStr.length - 1);
                        jsStr += "];";
                        eval(jsStr);
                        if (typeof (datalist) != 'undefined') {
                            response(jQuery.map(datalist, function (items) {
                                if (items.id != undefined) {
                                    return {
                                        value: items.name,
                                        id: items.id
                                    }
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minlength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (Type == 1) {
            document.getElementById("txtUser" + MemCount).value = ui.item.value;
        }
        else if (Type == 2) {                
            document.getElementById("txtRole" + MemCount).value = ui.item.value;
        }
    },
    open: function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function (event) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

When I try to Debug this autocomplete, the data is coming at the end of `response(jQuery.map(datalist, function (items)` statement. But the `select:` option is not firing.

**EDIT**

The below screenshot shows how the data is formed.

[image: Items]

And this is what is present in the Server-Side Users.aspx.vb Page_Load Event

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Write(GetUserName(Request.QueryString("UserName")))
Response.End()
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First. In the response, you check the data variable in swith. And you get it as a string.
Second. the best way to work with ajax is JSON.

```
jQuery.ajax({
         url: url,
         dataType: 'json'
```

On successful response:
Make parsing.

```
json = JSON.parse(data)
```

And then you already apply your logic, I work with individual object variables.

```
swith(json.string){ .... }
```

And it will be easier to fill Textbox controls with the necessary parameters: json.user - the variable will contain an array of data about users.

Update code:

```
jQuery("#" + e.id).autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    var txtSearch = jQuery("#" + e.id).attr("id");                        
    var t = jQuery("#" + txtSearch).val();      
    var URL = "../Users.aspx?UserName=" + t;           
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        /*
        * format respone data (string!!!) ->   {"result": [{"id": 1,"item": 2},{"id": 1,"item": 2}],"found": "VALUESFOUND"}
        */
        success: function (data) {
            let json = JSON.parse(data);
            switch (json.found) {                        
                case 'NOVALUESFOUND':
                    var rftspanID = e.id.replace("txt", "span");
                    break;
                default:
                    var rftspanID = e.id.replace("txt", "span");
                    response(jQuery.map(json.result, function (items) {
                            if (items.id != undefined) {
                                return {
                                    value: items.name,
                                    id: items.id
                                }
                            }
                        }));
            }
        }
    });
},
minlength: 1,
select: function (event, ui) {
    if (Type == 1) {
        document.getElementById("txtUser" + MemCount).value = ui.item.value;
    }
    else if (Type == 2) {                
        document.getElementById("txtRole" + MemCount).value = ui.item.value;
    }
},
open: function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
},
close: function (event) {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
}
```

});

Comment: just do not forget to give a string in json format in the northern part

Comment: The `switch` case is working perfectly. And where should I use `json = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: How can I use `json.user` or `json.string` here.

Comment: Now when I use `dataType: 'json'`, it is not coming inside `jQuery.ajax` function.

Comment: @Alex_JMcL - Do you have any other ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I have updated your code

Comment: Found the problem. It is the problem with jQuery - Prototype.js file. Because of this it is not running properly.

Comment: Everything is possible.